# Get Identity of destination table when using **DELETE FROM ... OUTPUT ... INTO**

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, output-clause

I use bellow code to archive old data in `ArchiveTable` and delete archived data from `SourceTable`

```
DELETE FROM SourceTable 
OUTPUT 
    DELETED.[ID], 
    DELETED.[Code],
    DELETED.[Title]
INTO ArchiveTable([OldID], [Code], [Title])
WHERE Condition
```

Structure of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [SourceTable](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [VARCHAR](16) NULL,
    [Title] [NVARCHAR](128) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [ArchiveTable](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OldID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [VARCHAR](16) NULL,
    [Title] [NVARCHAR](128) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ArchiveTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) 
GO
```

I need to return deleted records and `ArchiveTable.[ID]` to application. I change the code like this:

```
DELETE FROM SourceTable 
OUTPUT 
    DELETED.[ID], 
    DELETED.[Code],
    DELETED.[Title]
INTO ArchiveTable([OldID], [Code], [Title])
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE Condition
```

This code return deleted records but I don't know how to get ID of  `ArchiveTable` for this records. Look at `ArchiveTable` structure, It has `OldID` column that refer to `SourceTable.ID` and `ID` column that it is an `Identity` column of `ArchiveTable`. I need to `ArchiveTable.ID` in final result.

Comment: how to get identity in the sense can you explain clearly what is the requirement

Comment: @Chanukya I need to all deleted record data from `SourceTable` and new ID from `ArchiveTable` that it assigned to each record after insert into `ArchiveTable`

Comment: as per my understanding ArchiveTable how newid is inserting into ArchiveTable

Comment: @Chanukya `ArchiveTable.ID` is a IDENTITY column and it has identity increment rule

Answer (score 3):

You can use a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE #DeletedRows(
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [VARCHAR](16) NULL,
    [Title] [NVARCHAR](128) NULL
)

DELETE SourceTable 
OUTPUT 
    DELETED.[ID], 
    DELETED.[Code],
    DELETED.[Title]
INTO #DeletedRows([ID], [Code], [Title])
WHERE Condition

INSERT ArchiveTable([OldID], [Code], [Title])
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT [ID], [Code], [Title]
FROM #DeletedRows

DROP TABLE #DeletedRows
```

A variant with a table variable

```
DECLARE @DeletedRows TABLE(
    [ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [VARCHAR](16) NULL,
    [Title] [NVARCHAR](128) NULL
)

DELETE SourceTable 
OUTPUT 
    DELETED.[ID], 
    DELETED.[Code],
    DELETED.[Title]
INTO @DeletedRows([ID], [Code], [Title])
WHERE Condition

INSERT ArchiveTable([OldID], [Code], [Title])
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
SELECT [ID], [Code], [Title]
FROM @DeletedRows
```

Comment: I would use a table variable for this, but the idea is the right idea.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Thank you for your comment! I've added a variant with a table variable too. It's my habit to use temporary tables. I've worked with MSSQL from 2000 version.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting variant using `DML` with `OUTPUT` in `SP` and `INSERT...EXEC...` after that:

Test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Title varchar(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE TestTableLog(
  LogID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  OperType char(1) NOT NULL,
  CHECK(OperType IN('I','U','D')),
  ID int NOT NULL,
  Title varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

DML procedures:

```
CREATE PROC InsTestTable
  @ID int,
  @Title varchar(10)
AS

  INSERT TestTable(ID,Title)
  OUTPUT inserted.ID,inserted.Title,'I' OperType
  VALUES(@ID,@Title)

GO

CREATE PROC UpdTestTable
  @ID int,
  @Title varchar(10)
AS

  UPDATE TestTable
  SET
    Title=@Title
  OUTPUT inserted.ID,inserted.Title,'U' OperType
  WHERE ID=@ID

GO

CREATE PROC DelTestTable
  @ID int
AS

  DELETE TestTable
  OUTPUT deleted.ID,deleted.Title,'D' OperType
  WHERE ID=@ID

GO
```

Tests:

```
-- insert test
INSERT TestTableLog(ID,Title,OperType)
EXEC InsTestTable 1,'A'

INSERT TestTableLog(ID,Title,OperType)
EXEC InsTestTable 2,'B'

INSERT TestTableLog(ID,Title,OperType)
EXEC InsTestTable 3,'C'

-- update test
INSERT TestTableLog(ID,Title,OperType)
EXEC UpdTestTable 2,'BBB'

-- delete test
INSERT TestTableLog(ID,Title,OperType)
EXEC DelTestTable 3
GO

-- show resutls
SELECT *
FROM TestTableLog
```

Maybe it'll be interesting to someone.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue and this resolved it.  First make sure you set this on the target table;

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [schema].[target_table_name] ON
```

And then define all the columns in both the DELETED section and the INTO list;

```
 DELETE [schema].[source_table]
 OUTPUT DELETED.[col1],
        DELETED.[col2],
        DELETED.[col3] 
    INTO [dest_table] ([col1],
                       [col2],
                       [col3])  
        FROM [schema].[source_table]
```